# JAVA - Error printing Japanese Emojis/Kaomojis/ASCII emojis

Tags: java, printing, ascii, emoji

I am coding in JAVA. I'm trying to print this (｡•́︿•̀｡) and other similar emojis in the console, but instead it is printing (￯ﾽﾡ￢ﾀﾢￌﾁ￯ﾸ﾿￢ﾀﾢￌﾀ￯ﾽﾡ). When I try printing similar emoji art, I keep getting the same issue where these random characters are printing instead.

I'm just using

```
System.out.print("(｡•́︿•̀｡)");
```

But this ends up printing (￯ﾽﾡ￢ﾀﾢￌﾁ￯ﾸ﾿￢ﾀﾢￌﾀ￯ﾽﾡ)

I also tried using \ to escape formatting in case that was the issue, like:

```
System.out.print("(\｡\•́\︿\•̀\｡)");
```

But this resulted in an illegal escape character error.

Comment: Your console would have to support Unicode - does it? Also, it looks like your code might think it should print UTF-16 - is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

All files on all modern systems are stored as a sequence of bytes.  Every byte is a numeric value from zero to 2⁸−1 (that is, 0 to 255).

Since all files consist of bytes, characters in text files—including Java source files—need to be stored as bytes.  When the characters consist only of [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Character_set) characters, this is easy to do:  There are only 127 ASCII characters, therefore each character corresponds to one of 127 values, so each character is represented by one byte value in the file.

However, when you want to represent characters which are not ASCII characters, like `｡•́︿•̀｡`, the system where you’re working must know how you want those characters to be represented as bytes.  There are hundreds of thousands of character values in existence, so one character cannot possibly fit into the byte value range.

The method for translating characters to bytes (and bytes to characters) is called a [Charset](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/charset/Charset.html), also known as a character encoding.

If you have non-ASCII characters in your source code, you need to tell the Java compiler how the file is representing those characters as bytes.  You need to tell the compiler what character encoding was used to save your source file.

On non-Windows systems, files are almost always saved using the [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoding.  In fact, it appears your file was saved as a UTF-8 file, which usually is the right thing to do.  UTF-8 is extremely common and is the best encoding to use in almost every case.

However, when you compiled your code, the Java compiler mistakenly believed that your file is in windows-1252 or a similar windows-12nn encoding.  These windows encodings are one-byte encodings, capable of representing no more than 256 characters.  The characters `｡•́︿•̀｡` are not valid in these encodings.

Your source file is a UTF-8 file, so `｡` is [represented as three bytes](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ff61/) in that file.  However, the Java compiler didn’t know that;  it thought each of those bytes was a separate character, because it was assuming a Windows encoding where every byte represents one character.

You need to tell the compiler which encoding was used to save your source file.  If you’re building on the command line, you can use the [-encoding](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/specs/man/javac.html#option-encoding) compiler option.  For example:

```
javac -encoding UTF-8 MyProgram.java
```

If you are using an IDE, you will need to open your project’s properties, find the compiler option for the character encoding, and change it to UTF-8.